# Avoid override App_Data when swapping from dev to production in Azure

Tags: azure

When swapping from development to production, is it possible to avoid overriding the App_Data folder on the production site?

My production site has around 2.000 files that are edited all the time in the App_Data folder. The only solution I can see right now, is to use another folder that is not a part of the web app, unless someone can help me to not override this folder on a swap. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I would recommend to move all files to a blob storage. Although Web App environments / plans give us some space for saving files locally, I would refrain from using it for anything else then temp storage.

Yes, the storage in Web App **is** persistent and reliable. But it also **is** limited. If you do not hit limit now, you may hit it in 2 weeks or 2 months or 2 years (when it will be a nightmare to migrate everything to a blob storage).

Having said that, back to your question - **no**, there is no option and no method to preserve anything, but settings across swapping (not app_data, not any other folder on the local file system). Because swapping is just swapping of DNS records and nothing physical or logical. Beside the settings you define for your slots. When you create a new application setting in the portal (IBIZA) - be it application setting or connection string, you have the option (checkbox) to say that this is a slot setting, so the value and the key will persist across slot swaps.

Still on the topic - particularly important is that the linked Source Control systems also "move around" with the slots. What I mean is:

Say you have production slot `super-web.azurewebsites.net` and you linked it to source control `super-web.github.com`.

Let us also have `staging-super-web.azurewebsites.net` and this slot is linked to source control `staging-super-web.github.com`.

If you now do slot swap you will end up with the following situation:

`super-web.azurewebsites.net` will be linked to `staging-super-web.github.com` source control

while

`staging-super-web.azurewebsites.net` will be linked to `super-web.github.com` source control.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will go the Blob way and avoid using App_data as I usually do when my sites not are hosted in Azure.